# Is there a need to break down input data into chunks of 16 bytes with AES-128 libraries (specifically OpenSSL)?

Tags: openssl, base64, aes

I want to encrypt data using AES-128 and Base-64 (using OpenSSL) and then send it over a local socket to the requesting client.

I am using a 16byte (128 bit) key along with input data. The input data may be less than or more than 16 bytes.
The problem is whenever my input data length crosses 16 bytes, the encryption fails and I am unable to get my data while using open SSL. Does this mandate me to send only 16 encrypted bytes over the socket at a particular instant of time ?

I have tried to loop of the encryption API multiple times (16 bytes at a time) but is there any other way ?

```
unsigned char aes_input[]="Hello Where are you How are you";
char *base64EncodeOutput2;
char* base64DecodeOutput2;
size_t test2;

/* Buffers for Encryption and Decryption */
unsigned char enc_out[sizeof(aes_input)];
unsigned char dec_out[sizeof(aes_input)];

/* AES-128 bit CBC Encryption */
AES_KEY enc_key, dec_key;
AES_set_encrypt_key(aes_key, sizeof(aes_key)*8, &enc_key);
AES_ecb_encrypt(aes_input, enc_out, &enc_key, AES_ENCRYPT);

/* Encoding over Base64 */
Base64Encode(enc_out, strlen(enc_out), &base64EncodeOutput2)
```

Comment: Your comment indicates that you mean to encrypt with CBC, but your code actually calls AES_ecb_encrypt. Which encryption mode did you mean to use?

Comment: OpenSSL can do what you want, but all your settings have to match the decrypting side. I recommend exploring the `EVP_` functions. You'll want to use `EVP_EncryptUpdate` to generate each packet.

Comment: You are doing this incorrectly. You should not be using the low level AES_* APIs for this kind of thing. As suggested by @RobNapier the correct APIs to use are the `EVP_Encrypt*` functions. See https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/EVP_Symmetric_Encryption_and_Decryption

Comment: I want to use EBC mode. Sorry for the discrepancy. I will explore the EVP_ functions and not use the AES_ API's. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Do EVP_ functions also convert the cipher text into base64 string ? Or this operation needs to be taken care of by using seperate base64 encoding and decoding API's as done in my code above ?

Comment: Okay, I got some refernces over the net for converted AES encrypted code into base64 encoding (http://www.ioncannon.net/programming/34/howto-base64-encode-with-cc-and-openssl/). Works like a charm ! Thanks a lot for your help.